# How to run 1000 users with in hour through Stepping Thread group

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I have a test plan where i have added stepped thread group with the following settings and i want to run it for 1 hr for 1000 users, with this settings it is taking more than 1hr. can anyone please guide?

also what is the calculation of it to calculate that how many users will take how much time to run with this settings
[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

If you want just 1000 users for one hour just go for normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

[image]

If you're forced to use Stepping Thread Group it would be something like:

[image]

If you want to [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)

[image]

For any other "calculations" make sure that the duration of each ramp-up step multiplied by the number of steps plus time to hold the load does not exceed 3600 or whatever is your desired test duration